# How do I autowire my webservices client in my WAR application (using Spring)?

Tags: spring, cxf, autowired

I’m using Maven 3.0.3, CXF 2.7.15, and Spring 3.2.11.RELEASE.  Using the JAX-WS Maven plugin,  web service client classes are auto-generated (plugin code below) ...

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsimport</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/wsdl</wsdlDirectory>
                <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                <packageName>org.collegeboard.bsorg</packageName>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

which include the below

```
package org.myproject.bsorg;

/**
 * This class was generated by the JAX-WS RI.
 * JAX-WS RI 2.1.3-b02-
 * Generated source version: 2.1
 * 
 */
@WebService(name = "OrganizationWebService", targetNamespace = "http://mainco.org/bsorg/")
@XmlSeeAlso({
    ObjectFactory.class
})
public interface OrganizationWebService {
```

Then I have my own service class, in which I try and reference the above through auto wiring …

```
package org.mainco.subco.myproject.service;

@Service("orgWsdlSvc")
public class OrgWsdlServiceImpl implements OrgWsdlService 
{
    @Autowired
    private OrganizationWebService m_ows;
```

When I deploy my WAR file, I get the error

```
09:20:17,846 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (MSC service thread 1-14) Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orgWsdlSvc': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.mainco.bsorg.OrganizationWebService org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.OrgWsdlServiceImpl.m_ows; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [org.mainco.bsorg.OrganizationWebService] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:290) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1148) [spring-beans-3.2.11.RELEASE.jar:3.2.11.RELEASE]
```

But I’m confused about how to properly autowire things in my web.xml and accompanying context files.  In my WEB-INF/web.xml, I have

```xml
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext-myproject.xml,
        classpath:/META-INF/spring/infrastructure.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>webAppRootKey</param-name>
    <param-value>myproject.webapp</param-value>
</context-param>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

In my WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml file I have

```xml
<!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco" />

<!-- Define spring bean for use with this app. -->
<bean id="localPropertyConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean> 

<!-- Define application properties for use in Spring classes -->
<util:properties id="applicationProperties" location="classpath:application.properties" />

<tx:annotation-driven />
```

and in my “applicationContext-myproject.xml”, I have

```
<util:properties id="applicationProperties" location="classpath:application.properties" />
<util:properties id="coreProperties" location="classpath:core.properties" />

<context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.subco" />
<context:component-scan base-package="org.mainco.bsorg" />

<bean id="sessionTimeoutInSeconds" class="java.lang.Long">
    <constructor-arg>
        <value>3600</value>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<!-- Enable annotation driven controllers, validation etc... -->
<mvc:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Define spring bean for use with this app. -->
    <bean id="localPropertyConfigurer"
            class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
            <property name="location">
                    <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="assert" class="org.mainco.subco.util.Assert" factory-method="createInstance" />

    <http-conf:conduit name="https://.*">
            <http-conf:tlsClientParameters secureSocketProtocol="TLSv1" disableCNCheck="true">
                    <sec:trustManagers>
                        <sec:keyStore type="JKS" password="${key.store.password}" resource="${key.store.file}" />
                    </sec:trustManagers>
                    <sec:keyManagers keyPassword="${key.manager.password}">
                        <sec:keyStore type="pkcs12" password="${private.key.password}" resource="${private.key.file}" />
                    </sec:keyManagers>
            </http-conf:tlsClientParameters>
    </http-conf:conduit>

<jaxws:client id="orgWebServiceClient"
    serviceClass="org.mainco.bsorg.OrganizationWebService"
    address="${wsdl.url}"
    /> 

<bean id="organizationWebService" class="org.mainco.bsorg.OrganizationWebService"></bean>
```

What do I need to do so I can autowire my web services client?

**Edit:** Per the suggestion given, I added the bean definition to my application context (see above) file, but received the following error upon deplyohing the application:

```
Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'orgWsdlSvc': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.myproject.bsorg.OrganizationWebService org.mainco.subco.myproject.service.OrgWsdlServiceImpl.m_ows; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'organizationWebService' defined in class path resource [META-INF/spring/applicationContext-myproject-mvc.xml]: Instantiation of bean failed; 
nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.mainco.bsorg.OrganizationWebService]: Specified class is an interface
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the bean definition in your *applicationContext-myproject.xml*.

```
   <!-- Definition for OrganizationWebService bean -->
   <bean id="organizationWebService" class="org.mainco.bsorg.OrganizationWebService"></bean>
```

See this for more examples:
http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-auto-wiring-beans-with-autowired-annotation/

EDIT:
You are making progress. Now spring is able to find the autowired candidate in the application context.

However, there is another problem, the candidate is an interface and spring is not able to instantiate it (neither does javac). So, you need to create a class to implement your interface and describe it in your application context (instead or describing an interface). So; you need to create a org.mainco.bsorg.OrganizationWebServiceImp class implementing org.mainco.bsorg.OrganizationWebService and change your application context to:

```
   <bean id="organizationWebService" class="org.mainco.bsorg.OrganizationWebServiceImp"></bean>
```

More info here: [Could not instantiate bean class: Specified class is an interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26721583/could-not-instantiate-bean-class-specified-class-is-an-interface)

EDIT2:
Look at https://jax-ws.java.net/2.2.1/docs/UsersGuide.html#3.1.2_Starting_from_a_WSDL_File

The documentation clarifies that:

1. Generate a service endpoint interface.
2. Implement the service endpoint interface.
3. Create a WAR file to deploy.

You need to implement the service endpoint interface with a concrete class  eg: OrganizationWebServiceImp

Comment: Hey I tried your suggestion (assuming you emant to add this to the WEB-INF/dispatcher-servlet.xml file), but got the same exception.  How does your bean tie back to the jaxws:client definition?  It doesn't seem to have any link.

Comment: Oops, you said the applciation context file.  Ok, this time I implemented your suggestion and got the error (included in my question) that deployment failed because the bean failed to deploy due to "Specified class is an interface".

Comment: I included the Maven JAXWS plugin generation code at teh beginning of my question.  That interface (marked with @WebService) was autogenerated by the plugin.  None of the autogenerated classes include an "implements OrganizationWebService".  It seems wrong to me that I would have to write my own implementing class, don't you think?

Comment: JAXWS generation from a contract (eg.:WSDL) was intended to generate an interface and the developer should implement it. See EDIT2.

Comment: Hi, I really appreciate your help with this.  Maybe I'm asking the wrong question.  I want to auto-generate a web service client from an existing WSDL where I can use generated client Java code to query and then retrieve values from the web service.  Why do I need to implement something?  Is there a plugin that can just auto-generate the web service client code for me?

Comment: By definition a WSDL is a contract which specifies what needs to be done and in which format; however, it does not specifies *how* to do it. That's way I do not see how to achieve what you want just with a WSDL. Imagine in the real world a contract that says "You will receive Internet at home"; someone still need to pass the cables, route packages, etc. The contract just say that you will receive internet, but does not say how. As a developer you implement how to do it (you still need to pass the cables).