# How to represent @Resource in spring XML

Tags: spring

I'm working with a program that currently uses Java Beans and need to recreate these Beans in another project that uses XML Beans. How can I represent the following line in XML?

```
@Resource(name="applicationIdCredentialProvider")
private CredentialProvider applicationIdCredentialProvider;
```

I'm currently using the following code to create a bean for the applicationIdCredentialProvider:

```
<bean id="applicationIdCredentialProvider" class="com.uprr.enterprise.security.credential.CredentialProvider"/>
```

But getting the error:

```
Could not instantiate bean class [com.uprr.enterprise.security.credential.CredentialProvider]: Specified class is an interface
```

Comment: It looks like `CredentialProvider` is an interface, and XML beans can only be created from a **class** that implements that interface (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26721667/4638529) to a similar question). Check your project and see if you can find the specific class(es) that implement `CredentialProvider` and change the `class` to what you find.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to import two classes as Beans using the following lines in my spring.xml file:

Add the following to < beans >:

```
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
```

Add the following after < beans >:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

The imported files should look like this:

```
<bean id="giveYourBeanAName" class="class.of.your.Java.object"/>
```